# Generate random sample of values in a range with replacements using numpy

Tags: numpy

`np.random.uniform(low, high, size)` does not give you replacement values.

Is there any way to generate sample values with replacements?

Comment: Do you mean a continuous range? Probability of getting the same value twice is zero in that case. That's more a maths than a numpy issue.

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

Ex: draw 10 samples from 0 to 10, with replacement.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=10)
# array([5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 8, 0, 6, 4, 8])
```

> See tons of examples on this post: [Numpy distributions and statistical funcitons: examples and reference](http://queirozf.com/entries/numpy-distributions-and-statistical-functions-examples-reference)

You can also use np.random.choice:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.choice(10,10,replace=True)
# array([5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 8, 0, 6, 4, 8])
```